# Flash + fancy uploader.. have to click twice on firefox

Tags: ajax, flash, mootools, google-swiffy

http://digitarald.de/project/fancyupload/3-0/showcase/attach-a-file/

That's the uploader plugin I'm using.

If you go there in firefox, you'll notice you have to click "attach a file" twice before it works. It seems to work fine in every other browser (that I've tested).

it's creating a flash object, and I'm not sure how to go about making it so you only click once in FF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with mooTools, but have you tried something like this? (attempted to write it in mooTools, but have no idea what I'm doing).

```
$('uploadLink').addEvent('click', function(){
    if(Browser.firefox) $('uploadLink').fireEvent('click');
});
```

or I suppose if it has to wait for the flash to be created, something like this:

```
$('uploadLink').addEvent('click', function(){
    if(Browser.firefox){
        var flashTimer = setTimeout(function(){
            clearTimeout(flashTimer);
            /// or however you make sure the flash has successfully been added to the page
            if($('flashContainer').getElements().length) $('uploadLink').fireEvent('click');
        },100);
    }
});
```

There's always the possibility that FF's security measures won't let you do something like this (mouse interactions with flash can be potentially harmful, as flash has FS access and stuff).

Depending on what your backend is, I'm highly in favor of skipping flash for file uploads when possible. One very well written plugin for such a task is available here:

http://valums.com/ajax-upload/

Good luck!

Comment: incredible plugin....... i looked for #$% ages for one and that was the best i found. This plugin is godsend!